# Implementing a POC Async Web Crawler

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asynchronous, web-scraping

I've created a small proof of concept web crawler to learn more about asynchrony in .NET.

Currently when run it crawls stack overflow with a fixed number of current requests (workers).

I was interested if I have made any common mistakes and if there is more of the framework / TPL I could be using to reduce the amount of code used.

To run it you would need to install the HtmlAgilityPack.

I am only really interested in feedback on program structure and the asynchronous aspects of it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var crawler = new WebCrawler();
        crawler.Start();
    }

    public class WebCrawler
    {
        private readonly HttpClient client;
        private const string SiteUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        private CrawlList crawlList;
        private const int MaxWorkers =5;
        private int workers;

        public WebCrawler()
        {
            client = new HttpClient();
            crawlList = new CrawlList();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            crawlList = new CrawlList();
            crawlList.AddUrl(SiteUrl);

            do
            {
                if (workers >= MaxWorkers) continue;

                if (!crawlList.HasNext()) continue;

                Interlocked.Increment(ref workers);

                Debug.Write("Workers " + workers);
                ProcessUrl(crawlList.GetNext());

            } while (crawlList.HasNext() || workers > 0);

        }

        private async void ProcessUrl(string url)
        {
            Debug.Print("Processing " + url);
            await client.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(ProcessResponse);
        }

        private async void ProcessResponse(Task<HttpResponseMessage> response)
        {
            Debug.Print("Processing response ");
            var html = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            var internalLinks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Where(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("/")).Select(x =>  SiteUrl + x.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
            internalLinks.ForEach(x => crawlList.AddUrl(x));

            Interlocked.Decrement(ref workers);
        }
    }

    public class CrawlList
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentBag<string> urlsToCrawl;
        private readonly ConcurrentBag<string> urlsCompleted;

        public CrawlList()
        {
            urlsToCrawl = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
            urlsCompleted = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
        }

        public bool HasNext()
        {
            return urlsToCrawl.Any();
        }

        public string GetNext()
        {
            string url;
            urlsToCrawl.TryTake(out url);
            urlsCompleted.Add(url);
            return url;
        }

        public void AddUrl(string url)
        {
            if (!UrlAlreadyAdded(url))
            {
                urlsToCrawl.Add(url);
                Debug.Print("Adding Url "  + url);
            }
        }

        public bool UrlAlreadyAdded(string url)
        {
            return urlsToCrawl.Contains(url) || urlsCompleted.Contains(url);
        }
    }
}
```

After runnning through all the suggestions I have a new implementation here below. I think this simple POC covers most of the issues people found with my code previously. Be great to hear back from all the contributers to what they think about it now?

Really liking the Task.WhenAny approach. Think my work is thread safe but that is my only concern.

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var crawler = new Crawler(5);

            try
            {
                crawler.Crawl("http://cask-marque.co.uk/").Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                foreach (var ex in e.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }


        public class Crawler
        {
            public readonly CrawlList CrawlList;
            private readonly List<Task<string>> runningTasks = new List<Task<string>>();
            private readonly HttpClient client;
            private readonly int maxConcurrentDownload;
            private const string BaseUrl = "http://cask-marque.co.uk";

            public Crawler(int maxConcurrentDownload)
            {
                CrawlList = new CrawlList();
                client = new HttpClient();
                this.maxConcurrentDownload = maxConcurrentDownload;
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = maxConcurrentDownload;
            }

            public async Task<bool> Crawl(string startUrl)
            {
                runningTasks.Add(ProcessUrl(startUrl));

                while (runningTasks.Any())
                {
                    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(runningTasks);
                    runningTasks.Remove(completedTask);
                    var pageHtml = await completedTask;

                    while (CrawlList.HasNext() && runningTasks.Count < maxConcurrentDownload)
                    {
                        var url = CrawlList.GetNext();
                        runningTasks.Add(ProcessUrl(url));
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }


            private async Task<string> ProcessUrl(string url)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("url " +  url);
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(content);
                var urls = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Where(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("/")).Select(x => BaseUrl + x.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
                CrawlList.AddUrls(urls);
                return content;
            }
        }

        public class CrawlList
        {
            public readonly Queue<string> UrlsToCrawl;
            public readonly List<string> UrlsCompleted;

            public CrawlList()
            {
                UrlsToCrawl = new Queue<string>();
                UrlsCompleted = new List<string>();
            }

            public bool HasNext()
            {
                return UrlsToCrawl.Any();
            }

            public string GetNext()
            {
                return UrlsToCrawl.Dequeue();
            }

            public void AddUrls(List<string> urls)
            {
                foreach (var url in urls)
                {
                    AddUrl(url);
                }
            }

            public void AddUrl(string url)
            {
                if (UrlAlreadyAdded(url)) return;

                UrlsToCrawl.Enqueue(url);
            }

            public bool UrlAlreadyAdded(string url)
            {
                return UrlsToCrawl.Contains(url) || UrlsCompleted.Contains(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in C# `async` (not at all) but I have the feeling you're doing something wrong. I see everywhere that `async void` is not a good idea. You probably want to implement a solution similar to [the one you can find in this Stack Overflow Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259689/download-html-pages-concurrently-using-the-async-ctp)

Comment: With `workers`, `MaxWorkers`, and the async code, it looks like you may want to take a look at [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx) (older .NET) or [TaskFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory(v=vs.110).aspx) while setting an input [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx) to limit the max concurrency.

Comment: @DanLyons That won't limit the number of concurrent downloads if you're going to use `await`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
crawler.Start();
```

This is very confusing naming. If a method is called `Start()`, I would expect it to, well, start the work and then return, not do all of the work. A better name would be something like `Run()`, or maybe even better, something more specific.

---

```
private const string SiteUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Why is this here? I think this makes much more sense as a constructor parameter, or maybe parameter to `Start()`.

---

```
private const int MaxWorkers =5;
```

Again, this should be probably configurable. Also, if you're processing a single website, it doesn't make much sense to have more workers than [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx), which by default is set to 2.

---

```
public WebCrawler()
{
    client = new HttpClient();
    crawlList = new CrawlList();
}

public void Start()
{
    crawlList = new CrawlList();
```

If you're going to set `crawlList` every time `Start()` is called, you don't need to set it in the constructor.

---

```
do
{
    …
} while (crawlList.HasNext() || workers > 0);
```

So, while some download is in progress, you're going to loop around and waste a whole CPU core doing nothing useful? That's a terrible idea. mariosangiorgio's answer has one way of solving this.

---

```
await client.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(ProcessResponse);
```

You don't need `ContinueWith()` here, that's what `await` is for:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
await ProcessResponseAsync(response);
```

This assumes that you're going to change `async void ProcessResponse(Task<HttpResponseMessage> response)` to `async Task ProcessResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response)`, following [the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175).

---

```
var internalLinks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Where(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("/")).Select(x =>  SiteUrl + x.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
```

Why is this all a single line? You should break it into multiple lines, to make it more readable:

```
var internalLinks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    .Where(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("/"))
    .Select(x =>  SiteUrl + x.Attributes["href"].Value)
    .ToList();
```

And you could also use query syntax to avoid some repetition:

```
var internalLinks =
    from node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    let href = node.Attributes["href"].Value
    where href.StartsWith("/")
    select SiteUrl + href;
```

Or maybe:

```
var internalLinks =
    from node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    select node.Attributes["href"].Value into href
    where href.StartsWith("/")
    select SiteUrl + href;
```

The difference is that the second version is going to be slightly more efficient that the first one, but I also think it's less readable.

Also, I removed `ToList()`, see below.

---

```
internalLinks.ForEach(x => crawlList.AddUrl(x));
```

I don't think `List.ForEach` should be used. Instead use `foreach`, or add something like `AddUrls()` to your collection.

---

```
public string GetNext()
{
    string url;
    urlsToCrawl.TryTake(out url);
    urlsCompleted.Add(url);
    return url;
}
```

So, when `urlsToCrawl` is empty, you're going to add `null` to `urlsCompleted` and then return it? That doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

If this method is supposed to be called only when `urlsToCrawl` is not empty, then it should throw an exception when it's called incorrectly.

---

```
public void AddUrl(string url)
{
    if (!UrlAlreadyAdded(url))
    {
        urlsToCrawl.Add(url);
        Debug.Print("Adding Url "  + url);
    }
}
```

This is not thread-safe. Since this method can be called from multiple threads at the same time, you can end up downloading the same URL multiple times.

Comment: All really well thought out constructive advice. Will mark as answer but the other suggestions have been upvoted and are also all excellent. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>         do
>         {
>             if (workers >= MaxWorkers) continue;
>
>             if (!crawlList.HasNext()) continue;
>
>             Interlocked.Increment(ref workers);
>
>             Debug.Write("Workers " + workers);
>             ProcessUrl(crawlList.GetNext());
>
>         } while (crawlList.HasNext() || workers > 0);
> ```

Assuming that the first time you hit this block of code you are set up for crawling, you could probably get rid of the first 2 if statements by making this a while loop instead of a do while, something like this

```
while (crawlList.HasNext() && workers > 0 && workers <= MaxWorkers)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref workers);
    Debug.Write("Workers " + workers);
    ProcessUrl(crawlList.GetNext());
}
```

I also assumed that you wouldn't want to try assigning a worker to the next item on the `crawlList` if there weren't anymore workers so I changed the or (`||`) to an and (`&&`)

I also assumed that you didn't want to go over your max number of workers so I added that into the conditional of the while statement as well.

---

I was looking at this, and thought that you probably want to wait for workers to get freed up and not actually exit the loop when the amount of workers are working are at the programs maximum, you probably want something that will keep the loop going until a worker is freed up.

So, something like this.

```
while (crawlList.HasNext() && workers > 0)
{
    if (workers > MaxWorkers)
    {
        continue;
    }
    Interlocked.Increment(ref workers);
    Debug.Write("Workers " + workers);
    ProcessUrl(crawlList.GetNext());
}
```

Comment: This still has the same problem as the original: it wastes a whole CPU core when downloading.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should clarify what `async` is for. It is true that it allows you to run some *slow* operation outside the main thread but it is not meant as a way to achieve parallelism. It is just a way to allow your application to continue processing without blocking on expensive operations. Have a look at [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Three-Essential-Tips-For-Async-Introduction) which explains it quite clearly.

You obtain multiple threads with your *fire and forget* execution deriving from `async void` but you should avoid using them. [They should be used only in event handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

You need a more structured approach. You need to create several `Task` instances and start them in parallel. Obviously, each task can perform async operations. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj155756.aspx) is a good starting point on how you can do that.

This is the code I came up with and that should do the trick in a cleaner way.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Linq;

namespace Async
{
    public class Crawler
    {
        private readonly HttpClient client;
        private readonly int maxConcurrentDownload;
        string baseUrl;

        public Crawler (HttpClient client, string baseUrl, int maxConcurrentDownload)
        {
            this.maxConcurrentDownload = maxConcurrentDownload;
            this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
            this.client = client;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Crawl(string startUrl)
        {
            var result = new List<string> (); // I know list is not the ideal data structure here. Let's use it for simplicity
            var pagesToProcess = new Queue<string> ();

            var runningTasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<string>>> ();
            runningTasks.Add (processUrl(startUrl));
            result.Add (startUrl);

            while (runningTasks.Any())
            {
                var firstCompletedTask = await Task.WhenAny (runningTasks);
                runningTasks.Remove (firstCompletedTask);
                var urlsFound = await firstCompletedTask;

                /*
                 * At this point we know the url we found in the page
                 * we finished to process. 
                 * It's time to enque them
                 */
                foreach (var url in urlsFound)
                {
                    if(!result.Contains(url))
                        pagesToProcess.Enqueue (url);
                }
                /*
                 * Now we should start some new Taks
                 * to process new pages
                 */
                while (pagesToProcess.Any () && runningTasks.Count < maxConcurrentDownload)
                {
                    var url = pagesToProcess.Dequeue ();
                    runningTasks.Add (processUrl (url));
                    result.Add(url);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> processUrl(string url)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Processing {0}", url);
            var response = await client.GetAsync (url);
            var childUrls = await ProcessResponse (response);
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} child urls for {1}", childUrls.Count, url);
            return childUrls;
        }

        private async Task<List<string>> ProcessResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            return doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Where(x => x.Attributes["href"].Value.StartsWith("/")).Select(x => baseUrl + x.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you start it:

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Starting up!");
        var crawler = new Crawler (new System.Net.Http.HttpClient (), "http://stackoverflow.com", 3);
        crawler.Crawl ("http://stackoverflow.com").Wait();
    }
```

Comment: "[async] is just a way to offload the expensive operation to a background thread" No! That's a complete misunderstanding of what async does. Properly implemented async IO operations don't use any threads while the operation is executing. And it is a good way to execute multiple operations in parallel, like your code shows.

Comment: Do you have any reference where I could learn how async is implemented?

Comment: You might start with [*There Is No Thread*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). But there is lots of information about async on the internet.

Comment: Really is an interesting way of solving the problem. Found this really helpful in getting my head around the kind of patterns used in Task based programming. May well try to refactor these suggestions in tonight.